# Silence command but not its output

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, filetype-tex

I use the following function to compile a LaTeX document

```
function! TeXCompile()
  let filepath = expand('%:p')
  execute "!cd $(dirname ".shellescape(filepath,1).") && pdflatex -synctex=1 ".shellescape(filepath,1)
endfunction
```

which I use with the autocmd

```
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <C-t> :call TeXCompile()<cr>
```

How can I change it so that the command itself (`:!cd $(dirname ...`) is not echoed to the commandline, but its output (the stuff after `This is pdfTex`) is?

[image]

Comment: If I had to guess, you probably can't...

Comment: @noibe Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (assuming it did address your problem adequately) and to award the bounty you have open. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @filbranden I know, I was waiting for the bounty to almost expire before accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ben said in the comments prompting the command used before its result is a built-in behavior that you can not change without modifying Vim's source code.

However a possible workaround is to use [`:h system()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) to avoid prompting anything and then showing the result of the command by yourself.

I did a test with the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F1> :let res = system('cd $HOME && ls') \| echo res<CR>
```

It will `cd` to the right directory, put the result of `ls` in the `res` variable and then echo the content of the variable showing the result of the command without showing the command itself

This is ugly but this is probably your best best.

---

Also a few unrelated but still relevant notes:

- Never use an `autocommand` without an `augroup`[`:h :augroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup)
- Don't create your filetype specific mapping with an autocommand you are bloating your config for nothing. Instead use a ftplugin [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)
- Instead of having a mapping to invoke `pdftext` you probaby want to have a read at [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27), [`:h :compiler`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler) and [`:h compiler-tex`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#compiler-tex)

Comment: I have only briefly looked into `makeprg`, `compiler` and `compiler-tex`, but from what I saw they need a makefile, correct? Even if it doesn't need one, what's the advantage of that method over cd-ing to the directory and calling `pdflatex`?

Comment: Actually I think only `compiler-text` requires a makefile. `compiler` is a way to set `makeprg` and `makeprg` can be basically any command you want. I mentioned these because this is the built-in way to do what you are trying to do, but `cd`ing and using `pdflatex` directly from a mapping has nothing wrong if it fits your needs. IMO the main advantage is that it let's you define a generic interface to "build stuff" and then you can define how to "build" each of your "stuff".

Comment: But yeah these last points were just to let you know these options exist. I still believe you would benefit from using a ftplugin instead an autocommand tho because it allows you to remove bloat from your config while leveraging the built-in behavior offered by Vim

Comment: Yeah I'll definitely look into ftplugins, I'm all about removing bloat and simplifying stuff. Btw, with the `makeprg` approach do I need to cd into the file directory or can I just call it by giving the name of the file?

Comment: You might want to mention using `:term` to run a command as well, which will allow you to see the output of the command as it runs. (`system()` will only give you the output once the command is completely finished.)

Comment: @noibe You can use `%` which is automatically replaced by the path of the file as the doc says [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27).

Comment: @filbranden We don't have much context here, but I think that if OP wants to remove a single line to not see the command they use, I would guess that opening a new buffer with a shell in it and which would show the command they use is not going to make them happy :)

Comment: @statox I know that `%` expands to the path of the file, but for (pdf)latex specifically you need to cd into the file directory. If you don't it still compiles without a problem, but all the output files (the pdf file, the log files etc) will be created not in the directory of the file, but in the directory from which you called pdflatex.

Comment: You will have to do some tests by yourself. I believe you need to `set autochdir` so that the current directory is updated when you edit new files and `:make` is executed in this directory but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @noibe For LaTeX take a look at the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) and [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) (a.k.a. latex-suite) plug-ins, which include many features to help you work with LaTeX documents, including "compiling" them into PDFs or other formats. (vimtex covers LaTeX too! Not just plain TeX.) Learning and using one of these will probably be much easier than rolling your own and should give you compilers and mappings that have been thoroughly tested to work well in most or all cases. I strongly advice you take a look at them!

Comment: @filbranden I'm already using vimtex, but I don't like its implementation of the compiler and I wanted to make a function for it myself, but I wasn't aware of the built in way to compile stuff, through the `:make` command.

Comment: @noibe Vimtex's author is really responsive and hangs around here... Can you expand on limitations or annoyances of vimtex's compiler implementation? Also consider filing an issue on vimtex's GitHub page.